# Excel Sumproduct with If or count?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am close to solving the formula, but stuck on excluding specific words and connecting that to a specific location in the formula. I am working with one dataset and need to do a count for a specific location, but exclude out certain names in that count. I need to exclude multiple words, but for example I want to exclude `Classpass` (1) `Class`, `classpass`,`LAclasspass`. But at the same time I want to make it specific for a location.

This is the formula I currently have.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Series<>"1- One Class (ClassPass)")*(Series<>"Classpass (1) Class")*(Series<>"LA - ClassPass - 1 Class")*(Series<>""))
```

But How would I tie to a specific location. This only get me the total number from everything in the dataset. Because in the data I have 30 different locatoins, but want to only count and exclude names for one specific studio at a time.

First image is the data and second image is the sheet where I want to do the formula and link to a specific location. If I was not clear just ask me any follow up questions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure I got it completely, but just to stimulate further clarification. How about adding `*(ROOM = B4)` to that `SumProduct` ?

Comment: Amazing! that was exactly what I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: I sometime find breaking problem down into smaller chunks, such as adding a column flag with 0 = exclude 1 = include. Use FIND formula to set flag how you want, then use  flag your SUMPRODUCT. Then you could have posed question say if filter column contains 1. That way you could focus in on the problem without giving helpers information overload on the complexities of name matching which was probably irrelevant to the meat of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As [answered by A.S.H in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794962/excel-sumproduct-with-if-or-count/49619699#comment74631476_43794962):

> Not sure I got it completely, but just to stimulate further clarification. How about adding *(ROOM = B4) to that SumProduct ?